# Multiple data enters the full calendar at the same time

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, fullcalendar

Get the data into the table with a button called showBom(index). Drag this table into the calendar. The problem is that as much data as the showBom(index) button is pressed is entered into the calendar at once. Why?

**Parent of calendar and dragtable**

```
  methods: {
    async showBom(index) {
      this.$store.commit('setBomData', []) 
      this.bomDatas = this.getBomData ? [...this.getBomData] : []

      this.showBomModal.fill(false)
      this.showBomModal = this.showBomModal.map(() => false)
      this.showBomModal[index] = true
      this.openedBomIndex = index

      const productUnit = this.planDatas[index].product_unit;
      const { id } = this.planDatas[index];
      this.$store.commit('setSelectedPlanId', id);

      this.setBomProductUnit(productUnit);

      this.$store.commit('setProductUnitData', productUnit)
      await this.$store.dispatch('getBom', { product_unit: productUnit })

      console.log(productUnit, id)
    },
```

**Tables and calendars that appear when you click showBom**

```
<!-- eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars -->
<!-- eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-syntax -->
<template>
  <div class="bom">
    <div class="bomTable-processList">
      <div>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th colspan="6">BOM 관리</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>미완 <input type="radio" aria-label="미완" name="bom" /></th>
              <th>작성중 <input type="radio" aria-label="작성중" name="bom" /></th>
              <th>작성완료 <input type="radio" aria-label="작성완료" name="bom" /></th>
              <th colspan="3"><button @click="putBom()">완료</button></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="external-events">
            <tr
              class="fc-event"
              v-for="(bomData, index) in getBomData"
              :key="index"
              draggable="true"
              @dragstart="handleDragStart($event, bomData)"
            >
                <td v-for="(process, pIndex) in bomData.process" :key="pIndex">{{ process }}</td>
              <td class="minusBtn">
                <button @click="deleteBom( bomDatas[index])">-</button>
              </td>
              <td class="upBtn">
                <button @click="moveRowUp(index)">▲</button>
              </td>
              <td class="downBtn">
                <button @click="moveRowDown(index)">▼</button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <processList />
    </div>
    <equipmentList />
    <div class="full">
      <div id="external-events"></div>
      <div id="calendar-container" @drop="handleDrop" @dragover="handleDragOver">
        <FullCalendar
          class="demo-app-calendar"
          ref="fullCalendar"
          :options="calendarOptions"
          :editable="true"
          :events="calendarEvents"
          @eventAdd="onEventAdd"
          @eventClick="handleEventClick"
          @drop="handleDrop"
          droppable="true"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script lang="js">
import processList from '@/components/detail/processList.vue'
import equipmentList from '@/components/detail/equipmentList.vue'

import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/vue'
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid'
import interactionPlugin, { Draggable } from '@fullcalendar/interaction'
import resourceTimelinePlugin from '@fullcalendar/resource-timeline'

export default {
  components: {
    FullCalendar,
    processList,
    equipmentList,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      draggedData: null,
      calendarOptions: {
        schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',
        plugins: [dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin, resourceTimelinePlugin],
        initialView: 'dayGrid1',
        slotDuration: '24:00:00',
        resources: [],
        events: [],
        height: 600,
        headerToolbar: {
          left: 'prev,next today',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'dayGrid1,dayGrid2',
        },
        views: {
          dayGrid1: {
            type: 'resourceTimelineDay',
            duration: { days: 30 },
            buttonText: '15',
          },
          dayGrid2: {
            type: 'resourceTimelineDay',
            duration: { days: 60 },
            buttonText: '30',
          },
        },
        dayHeaderFormat: {
          weekday: 'short',
          month: 'numeric',
          day: 'numeric',
          omitCommas: true,
        },
        editable: true,
        droppable: true,
        eventResizableFromStart: true,
        eventDidMount: this.handleEventMount,
      },
      removeAfterDrop: false,
      calendarEvents: [],
    }
  },
  watch: {
    getBomData: {
      handler() {
        this.$nextTick(() => {
          this.initializeDraggable();
        });
      },
      deep: true,
      immediate: true,
    },
    facilityDatas: {
      deep: true,
      handler() {
        this.calendarOptions.resources = this.facilityDatas.map((facility, index) => ({
          id: index.toString(),
          title: facility.facility_name,
        }))
      },
    },
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['getBomData', 'getProductUnitData', 'getFacilityData']),
    facilityDatas: {
      get() {
        return this.getFacilityData
      },
      set(value) {
        const updatedValue = value.map((item) => ({
          ...item,
        }))
        this.$store.commit('setFacilityData', updatedValue)
      },
    },
    bomDatas: {
      get() {
        return this.$store.getters.getBomData;
      },
      set(value) {
        const updatedValue = value.map((item) => ({
          ...item,
        }))
        this.$store.commit('setBomData', updatedValue)
      },
    },
    productUnit() {
      return this.getProductUnitData
    },
  },
  async mounted() {
    const payload = {
      product_unit: this.productUnit,
    }
    await this.$store.dispatch('getBom', payload)
    this.bomDatas = this.getBomData ? [...this.getBomData] : []

    this.calendarOptions.resources = this.facilityDatas.map((facility, index) => ({
      id: index.toString(),
      title: facility.facility_name,
    }))

    await this.initializeDraggable()

    this.fullCalendar = this.$refs.fullCalendar.$refs.calendar
  },
  methods: {
    moveRowUp(index) {
      if (index > 0) {
        const temp = { ...this.bomDatas[index] }
        const prevData = { ...this.bomDatas[index - 1] }

        const tempProcessOrder = temp.process_order
        temp.process_order = prevData.process_order
        prevData.process_order = tempProcessOrder

        this.$set(this.bomDatas, index, prevData)
        this.$set(this.bomDatas, index - 1, temp)
        this.bomDatas = [...this.bomDatas]
      }
    },

    moveRowDown(index) {
      if (index < this.bomDatas.length - 1) {
        const temp = { ...this.bomDatas[index] }
        const nextData = { ...this.bomDatas[index + 1] }

        const tempProcessOrder = temp.process_order
        temp.process_order = nextData.process_order
        nextData.process_order = tempProcessOrder

        this.$set(this.bomDatas, index, nextData)
        this.$set(this.bomDatas, index + 1, temp)
        this.bomDatas = [...this.bomDatas]
      }
    },
    async putBom() {
      for (const bomData of this.bomDatas) {
        if (bomData.id) {
          const { id, process_order } = bomData
          await this.$store.dispatch('putBom', { id, process_order })
        }
      }

      const payload = {
        product_unit: this.productUnit,
      }
      await this.$store.dispatch('getBom', payload)
    },

    async deleteBom(bomData) {
      console.log(bomData)
      if (window.confirm('정말로 삭제하시겠습니까?')) {
        await this.$store.dispatch('deleteBom', {
          product_unit: bomData.product_unit,
          process_order: bomData.process_order,
        });

        const payload = {
          product_unit: this.productUnit,

        }
        await this.$store.dispatch('getBom', payload)
      }
    },
    handleEventClick(info) {
      if (confirm('삭제하시겠습니까?')) {
        info.event.remove()
        const index = this.calendarEvents.findIndex((event) => event.id === info.event.id)
        if (index !== -1) {
          this.calendarEvents.splice(index, 1)
        }
      }
    },
    handleEventMount(info) {
      const eventEl = info.el
      eventEl.addEventListener('dblclick', () => {
        this.handleEventClick(info)
      })
    },
    onEventAdd(info) {
      const { event } = info

      const newEvent = {
        title: event.title,
        start: event.start,
        allDay: event.allDay,
      }
      this.calendarEvents.push(newEvent)
    },
    handleDragStart(event, bomData) {
      event.preventDefault()
      if (bomData) {
        event.dataTransfer.setData('text', JSON.stringify(bomData))
        this.draggedData = {
          product_unit: bomData.product_unit,
          process_name: bomData.process,
        }
      } else {
        console.error('bomData is undefined or null')
      }
    },

    handleDrop(event) {
      event.preventDefault()
      const dragData = this.draggedData
      this.draggedData = null

      if (dragData) {
        const dateClickedArg = {
          date: this.fullCalendar.getApi().getDate(),
          allDay: true,
        }

        const newEvent = {
          title: `${dragData.product_unit} - ${dragData.process}`,
          start: dateClickedArg.date,
          allDay: dateClickedArg.allDay,
        }

        this.calendarEvents.push(newEvent)

        if (this.removeAfterDrop) {
          const index = this.bomDatas.findIndex((data) => data === dragData)
          if (index !== -1) {
            this.bomDatas.splice(index, 1)
          }
        }
      }
    },
    initializeDraggable() {
      const containerEl = document.getElementById('external-events')
      if (containerEl) {
        const eventElements = containerEl.getElementsByClassName('fc-event')
        Array.from(eventElements).forEach((eventEl, index) => {
          new Draggable(eventEl, {
            eventData: () => {
              const bomData = this.bomDatas[index]
              return {
                title: `${bomData.product_unit} - ${bomData.process}`,
              }
            },
          })
          eventEl.addEventListener('dragstart', (event) => {
            const bomData = this.bomDatas[index]
            const dragData = {
              product_unit: bomData.product_unit,
              process_name: bomData.process_name,
            }
            event.dataTransfer.setData('text', JSON.stringify(bomData))
            this.draggedData = dragData
          })
        })

        const calendarContainerEl = document.getElementById('calendar-container')
        if (calendarContainerEl) {
          calendarContainerEl.addEventListener('drop', this.handleDrop)
          calendarContainerEl.addEventListener('dragover', this.handleDragOver)
        }
      }
    },
    handleDragOver(event) {
      event.preventDefault()
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

This is a video of a bug.
https://youtu.be/ss0SatTlyXA

Comment: I don't know React code very well, but I can see that you are calling `this.initializeDraggable` from more than one place. Possibly there are multiple executions of this function (you can add some console logging inside it, so you can see exactly when it is called, and how often). I mention it because within this function there are lots of calls to `addEventListener`, which set new listeners for dragging and dropping of all the draggable elements. It never removes any existing listeners.

Comment: From your video, it seems that every time you click on an item on the left, it probably calls `initializeDraggable` again, which then adds new  event listeners to the draggable elements. But the old ones are not removed, so then if you drag an element, it will execute all the previously-added listeners at the same time, which is why you see the number of elements added to calendar increases by 1 each time you repeat the drag operation.

Comment: @ADyson   thank you! The error does not occur because it is fixed so that it occurs only once when the page is opened.

Comment: Sorry I don't know what you mean exactly. Are you saying the problem is solved now, or do you mean that you think my theory is wrong?

Comment: @ADyson sorry i don't speak english well I mean thank you for solving it.

Comment: No problem. If you wrote some code for the solution, please share it below as an Answer, so that others may benefit from it, and you can get upvotes for it. (See also [answer]). That way, it also shows to others that your question is solved and does not need any more answers. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 watch: {
    getBomData: {
      handler() {
        this.$nextTick(() => {
          this.initializeDraggable();
        });
      },
      deep: true,
      immediate: true,
    },
}
```

I deleted the above part and called it from mounted.